# Handling Pop-up using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, popup, captcha

I am doing web scraping and trying to do login through selenium chromedriver. Login page has 3 fields Username, Password and Captcha. I am using `pytesseract` to bypass captcha and using an infinite loop for login if the entered captcha is not correct but I am getting `UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: Invalid captcha characters please enter again Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Invalid captcha characters please enter again}` error.

Code to automate login is:

```
while(1):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\ankit19.gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form[@id='form1']/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/img")
    #get_captcha(driver, img, "captcha.png")
    location = img.location
    size = img.size
    #saves screenshot of entire page
    driver.save_screenshot("captcha.png")
    image = Image.open("captcha.png")
    left = location['x']
    top = location['y'] 
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
    image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
    image.save("captcha.png", 'png')  # saves new cropped image
    captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    captcha = captcha.replace(" ", "").strip()
    txtUserName="user"
    txtPassword = "pwd"
    query = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txtUsername']")))    
    query.send_keys(txtUserName)
    query = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='txtPassword']")))    
    query.send_keys(txtPassword)
    query = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='txtinput']")))    
    query.send_keys(captcha)    
    element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='btnSubmit']")))
    element.click()
    get_url=driver.current_url
    print(get_url)
    if get_url == 'home_page_url':
        break
    else:
        sleep(5)
        driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
        print(driver.current_url)
        driver.get("login_page_url")
        print(driver.current_url)
```

For wrong entered captcha, pop-up window got clicked ok using `accept()` function but In the else part above, I have written some `print` statements to detect which statement is not working fine, So, I can see nothing is printed from the else part when wrong captcha is entered and also, username and password are also not entered automatically which should be done due to infinite loop but for correct entered captcha, `print` statement is working fine.

So, can anyone please help me to resolve this error, if it is possible to do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: without the url used, it will be difficult to help you

Comment: Yes @Frenchy, I can understand but it is from business, So, I can't provide the user name and password because If I give url then I have to give username and password also. I have resolved my issue here. I was using  "driver.switch_to_alert().accept()" at the wrong place in above code. It should be above "get_url=driver.current_url" statement.